# How to make Java object from XML?

Tags: java, xml, swing, object, xml-parsing

I have a lot of XML files as below.
How can I create Java class (Java object) from it automatically? 
How to update key and value in the String?

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
     <appSettings>
       <add key="MODE" value="1"/>   
       <add key="NAME" value="DIRN2"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>`

public void createPc("pc.xml"){
      XStream xstream = new XStream();
      Pc newpc = (Pc)xstream.fromXML(pc.xml);

     // updating key and value
       ????????????
 }
```

Comment: Try [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9409538/579580)

Answer (score 1):

Use [JaxB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/). Inorder to create objects, using JaxB, all you need to do is define XSD for your XMLs and generate the classes for your XSD.

Comment: You do not require an XML schema to use JAXB (JSR-222).  You can start with Java classes and use annotations to control the XML representation:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

http://www.castor.org/

Creates automatically the classes you need from the xmls.

You need to marshall and unmarshall it to populate the java objects and update the xml file.